# A question on pulse conditioning implementation

Tags: operational-amplifier, pulse

Here is the aim of the circuit from input-output perspective:
Below on the left side of the arrow are the possible input pulse train signals. On the right side are the desired sharpened output pulses.

input .............. output

0 - 100mV --> 0 – 5V

0 - 3V --> 0 – 5V

0 - 8V --> 0 – 5V

0 - 12V --> 0 – 5V

3 - 12V --> 0 – 5V

2 - 5V --> 0 – 5V

How is it possible to implement this without using a level-shifter? By using a single or maybe two opamps.

Any ideas appreciated.

Comment: "level shifter" can mean anything

Comment: posdible to make a 2-5V  pulse to 0-5V with single supply rail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At minimum, you would need a selector switch, or some means of telling your "pulse conditioner" what input to expect. Otherwise your "pulse conditioner" would have to be an anticipatory system (which isn't going to happen).

Envision the simplest op-amp comparator with a switch to select different threshold voltage to determine low and high levels, as a minimum system. The op-amp would have to use power rail of at least 12 volts, to accommodate your highest voltage input.

Answer (score 1):

If this thing is feeding an ADC with decent resolution, I'd suggest just 2 input ranges:

- 0 to 12V via a 2.4:1 attenuator,
- something like 0 to 0.25V via a x20 amplifier,

One switch between them, and perform the rest of the scaling in software. It'll be cheaper and more reliable.

But you haven't given us any context or design constraints, so this may not be a solution in your specific case. If you're dealing with short pulses and a slow sampling ADC, for example, this will not work well.

Comment: How about  3 - 12V --> 0 – 5V case?

Comment: You know it's possible to subtract in software, right?

Answer (score 1):

With no details on your "pulse trains" (pulse width, period, rise/fall times, etc.), it's difficult to be specific, but if the circuit needs to be autonomous (no manual adjustments), then something like the following should work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fxxI5O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The peak detectors produce outputs that are equal to the maximum excursions of the input signal, and the resistors establish a threshold that's halfway in between. The comparator then produces squared-up pulses based on when the input signal crosses that threshold.

Details of the peak detectors depend on the nature of the pulses and how fast the peak levels can change, left as an exercise for the reader. They will typically be opamp-based "ideal" half-wave rectifiers.

Answer (score 0):

What Dave said (+1), but I want to elaborate.

The basic problem with your requirements is that you haven't told us how we're supposed to distinguish between the 0-3 V and 3-12 V input cases, for example.  Because of these two, there is no single fixed voltage to compare the input against.  This leaves three options:

The signal switches modes without any indication from past behavior.  In this case the circuit can't know what is intended by a 3 V level, for example.  Is that a 0-3 V signal so clearly high, or a 3-12 V signal so clearly low?  In this case, something else will have to give additional information to the circuit, probably in the form of a threshold voltage.

The upper and lower voltages of the input pulses change slowly relative to the occurance of both the high and low levels.  This comes up occasionally in electronics, and is the situation Dave's answer is for.  In fact, it's common enough to have the name *data slicer*.  A typical application is receiving pulses via radio where the amplitude can vary significantly due to distance and other factors, and there can be a different DC offset on the pulses due to how the receiver works.

The general answer is to capture the local min/max, then average them to become the threshold the signal is compared to.  The min/max values decay toward each other slowly over time so that the decay is small during the period of any one pulse.  You'd also typically add a little hysteresis to the threshold detector to get good crisp edges out and to provide a little noise immunity right at the threshold voltage.  The hysteresis will need to be small in your case since you still have to detect only a 100 mV pulse.

One problem with analog data slicers like this is the time it takes to adjust to a new pulse amplitude.  This is why radio communication schemes that use such data slicers in the receiver typically send a *preamble*.  It is a part of the message that can be lost, with the purpose being to provide enough pulses so that the data slicer min/max levels can settle.

If this pulse stream is slow enough, then you can do a better data slicer in a microcontroller.  There you are not limited to linear filters and can easily remember past values.  I have used such a technique with very good results to data slice 10 kbit/s manchester encoded streams.  The manchester scheme guarantees no level lasts for more than one bit time, so a memory of samples a little more than that is guaranteed to contain a recent min and max level.  I usually sample the manchester signal at around 10x the bit rate and therefore store 12 samples or so.  Each new sample, I update the history of stored samples, find the min/max of the list, then compare the new sample to that to decide whether it is high or low.  Even better, you average the last 1/2 bit worth of samples, then threshold that.  This gives additional noise immunity in a way that would be very difficult to achieve with analog electronics.

This data slicing methoed has worked so well that I've had a micro correctly decoding manchester packets that I had a hard time seeing the pulse levels in the noise on the scope.

You are really looking for fast edges.  In that case, a differentiator will work.  However, this is particularly susceptible to noise.  It's not something you want to do unless you know you're input signal is quiet and flat except for the transitions between levels.